# I added an operators to give spaces between the two strings but it still doesn't work

Tags: python, string, input, output, letter-spacing

I was trying to make a name input that whenever you type a name it places on the welcome sign of the game. The only problem I am experiencing is that the name I input never has spaces between it, despite that I placed an operator to give it a space

```
name = input("what is your name:")
print("Welcome to the Casino" + name + "now go play till get broke")
```

and this is the output result: `Welcome to the CasinoMikenow go play till get broke`

Comment: What do you mean by *"operator to give it a space"*, you are not adding any space

Comment: Whitespace outside the `str` values is irrelevant.

Comment: It might help if you think about space just as another character. So if you need it - include it inside the string.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just add a space after 'Casino' and before 'now'. A better way would be to use an [fstring](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

For example:

```py
name = input("what is your name: ")
print(f'Welcome to the Casino {name} now go play till get broke')
```

Output:

```
what is your name: Jordan
Welcome to the Casino Jordan now go play till get broke
```

**Edit**: Here are a few resources on format string literals:

- ['f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python' article on RealPython.com](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)
- ['Python f-strings: Everything you need to know!'article on DataGy.io](https://datagy.io/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 1):

Their are many ways to solve this problem for example:

1. You can add space after the word "Casino" and before the word "now"

   print("Welcome to the Casino" + name + "now go play till get broke")
2. You can use "," instead of using "+" to separate multiple values in print statement:

   print("Welcome to the Casino", name, "now go play till get broke")

Answer (score 0):

"Welcome to the casino " + name + " now go play"

type it like this add a space at the end

Or just

```py
name = input("what is your name: ")
print(f"Welcome to the Casino {name}")
```

Comment: The commas are part of the syntax of the call to `print`, nothing to do with constructing a single string.